# why api data is not coming? my code is right or wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js, console.log

This is api data coming from some website...

```
date: (...)
dateTimeGMT: (...)
matchStarted: (...)
squad: (...)
team-1: (...)
team-2: (...)
toss_winner_team: (...)
type: (...)
unique_id: (...)
winner_team: (...)
```

If I write `console.log(response.date)` or `console.log(response.toss_winner_team)` then code works fine, but if I write `console.log(response.team-1)` or `console.log(response.team-2)` then `NaN` is coming in result.

You can see api data in attached picture:

[image]

Comment: what is `response.team-2` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is trying to evaulate such expression. Try accessing it array style:

```
console.log(response["team-1"])
```

What are you actually trying to do? If the `response` is an array you should iterate over the response first:

```
response.forEach(row => console.log(row["team-1"]));
```

Comment: I don't know what's not working for you, because you didn't paste your code as you should.

Comment: getData () {
  
    axios.get('http://cricapi.com/api/matches', {
  params: {
    apikey: 'GBWsx5I1qWQta3pXPjmzRpYJCzz2'
  }
}).then(response =>{
    (this.Player=response.data.matches);
    console.log(response.data.matches.team-1);
}  )},

Comment: Thank you for your apiKey. By the way, `matches` is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

If the property name is "team-1" then access it like 
`response["team-1"]`.

Doing response.team-1 considered as subtraction on property value.

If the data is integer in the property (response.team) you can do -1 on it by
`console.log(parseInt(response.team)-1);`

Comment: Show your code what have you written. else how can we check?

Answer (score 0):

```
response.team-1
```

team-1 is not a legit name for javascript variable so you need to use array with string calling instead `response["team-1"]`

Comment: getData () {
  
    axios.get('http://cricapi.com/api/matches', {
  params: {
    apikey: 'GBWsx5I1qWQta3pXPjmzRpYJCzz2'
  }
}).then(response =>{
    (this.Player=response.data.matches);
    console.log(response.data.matches["team-1"]);
}  )},

Comment: why are you doing response.data.matches["team-1"]? you are accessing  toss_winner_team property like "response.toss_winner_team" the "team-1" property is also in same structure so just try response.["team-1"]